# сертификат: как проверить, что он валидный?

Tags: letsencrypt, certbot, certificate

Уважаемые господа, я разбираюсь с неким более сложным вопросом, но мне надо понять, как проверять валидность сертификатов.

Каких? - любых, в том числе, "самоподписанных"

Моя логика такая: сертификат - это файл. ( *я не совсем тупой, я специально упрощаю* )

если я "беру сертификат у надежного поставщика" (например, у letsencrypt) - то это "хороший сертификат", с которым моя система будет работать.

А вот что делать, если мне налдо выпустить свой сертификат? Как мне проверить, "хороший" это сертификат, или "плохой"?

Comment: Свой сертификат - автоматически плохой, потому что никакая система не будет доверять ему по умолчанию. А чтобы он был по умолчанию хорошим, надо уговаривать майкрософтов с гуглами и прочими мозиллами добавить сертификат своего центра сертификации в их хранилища доверенных сертификатов

Comment: так валидный или хороший? можно вот так проверять дату `cat your_file.cer | openssl x509 -noout -dates`

Comment: господа, спасибо, я так понял, что возиться с самоподписанными сертификатами - себе дороже...

Comment: ну как сказать. любой гость сможет сделать свой самоподписанный сертификат и подменить. И вся система идет лесом.

Comment: в целом да, как уже сказали выше если валидность это доверительно отношения к нему например браузера, то это летсэнкрипт или купленные сертификаты и есть миллион сервисов по проверке, гуглится на 2 щелчка, если вам зачем то нужны именно сами сертификаты в том числе самоподписанные то следует уточнить параметры валидности